# Struggling with async/await C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I read alot about `async/await`, but I still have some lack in understanding the following situation.

My question is, should I implement my "wrapper" methods as in `DoSomething()` or like in `DoSomethingAsync()`.

So what's better (and why): Do I use `await` in wrapper methods or return the Task directly?

```
        public static async void Main()
        {
            await DoSomething();
            await DoSomethingAsync();
        }

        private static Task DoSomething()
        {
            return MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync();
        }

        private static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            await MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public class MyLibrary
        {
            public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
            {
                // Here is some I/O
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `async main` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app for more info.

Comment: This answer could be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808475/how-to-force-execution-to-stop-till-asynchronous-function-is-fully-executed

Comment: See [Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Berin's answer is good but does not explicitly address the particular case in your question, which is the following example:

**1: Returning the Task directly**

```
private static Task DoSomething()
{
    return MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

**2: Awaiting the Task and returning the result**

```
private static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

In this case, the only difference between returning the `Task` directly and awaiting the `Task` and returning the response is that - in the latter case - a state machine must be created by the framework to manage the starting, suspending and continuing of the method awaiting the `Task`. This incurs some performance overhead.

Generally speaking, if you can just return a `Task` and allow it to be awaited higher up, you should. In most (but certainly not all) real cases, however, this won't be possible as you will want to perform some processing of the result before returning (and this is exactly what async/await helps you to achieve).

Comment: You should also note that `async` implicitly creates the `Task` for you, while a regular method needs to call `Task.StartNew()` if it wants to return a `Task` object itself.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch only if it's the intention to actually create a new Task - in this case the Task is already supplied by `MyLibrary` and can simply be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Shouldn't you use Task.FromResult() instead Task.StartNew() when returning as Task from  regular method?

Comment: @coalmee, `Task.FromResult(quicklyGetResult())` - because it just wraps already computed (sync or async) result, but `Task.Run(() => slowlyGetResult())` - to start computing result asyncronously. So the answer is `it depends`.

Comment: is'nt the 1st one block the caller thread?

Comment: That's not the only difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run

Comment: @Noseratio of course - using `await` rather than not using it at all will introduce subtleties and gotchas associated with async/await - I was focusing on the (lack of) behavioural difference between a successful `return await x` and `return x` as that's what the question seemed to call for. Probably should have qualified that though.

Answer (score 8):

Async/Await are still relatively new, but there are some good practices to help clarify an API.  The basics are this:

- A method declaring itself as `async` means it is expecting to `await` later on
- `async` implicitly creates a `Task` for you.
- `await` is like a bookmark.  The application resumes where the await keyword was used.
- You cannot `await` anything that is not `IAwaitable` (most commonly a `Task`) ([citation](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern))

In an application where there are both asynchronous calls and synchronous calls, we've adopted a naming convention:

- `async` calls return `Task` or `Task<T>` and append the word `Async` to the end of the name.
- Synchronous calls (the default) simply work like any method does and there is no special convention.

Often, there can be two methods which do the same thing, but one is synchronous and the other not.  You can either implement it two different ways, or you can wrap one with the other.  It really depends on your needs and what is going to give you the more responsive application.

In the example above, the proper way to handle async and normal method calls would be for `MyLibrary` to expose two methods.  The example would be like this:

```
 public static class MyLibrary
 {
     public static void DoSomething()
     {
         // do some work
     }

     public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
     {
         // do similar work but use async API,
         // can also simply call DoSomething().
     }
 }

 // In another part of code would be called like this:
 public static async Task BiggerMethod()
 {
     MyLibrary.DoSomething();
     await MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync();
 }
```

What you want to avoid is wrapping an `async` method with a regular method.  As soon as you work with the `Task` directly, you lose all benefits of `async` and `await` and you introduce places where your code can deadlock.

Comment: for the sake of truth, `You cannot await anything that is not a task` statement is vague :) you can await any `awaitable`, which doesn't have to be task

Comment: @pkuderov, thank you.  That's actually something I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in case of one-liners.
But in case of `at least two-async-liners`, e.g.:

```
public static async void Main()
{
    await DoSomething();
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}

private static Task DoSomethingTwice()
{
    var do1 = MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync();

    // when you await DoSomethingTwice, next line's reached
    // when do1 task may not be completed
    var do2 = MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync();

    // return what???
    // how to combine them?

    // okay, you can do that
    return Task.WhenAll(do1, do2)
}

private static async Task DoSomethingTwiceAsync()
{
    await MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // when you await DoSomethingTwiceAsync, next line's reached 
    // when prev-line task is completed
    await MyLibrary.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public class MyLibrary
{
    public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        // Here is some I/O
    }
}
```

Summary:

- if you have to organize you method as a chain of sequential asyncronous peaces of work: `doAsync1()` -> `doAsync2()` -> `doAsync3()`,

i.e. every next peace needs complete result of previous one, then you should await every call as:

```
async Task DoAsync()
{
    await doAsync1();
    await doAsync2();
    await doAsync3();
}
```

- but you cannot use await in `non-async` methods. So your cannot do it in your `Task DoSomething()` style, only as `async Task DoSomethingAsync()`.
- if there's no asyncronous chain - you can do whatever you want as in my first example above

Comment: Important to note that the above (`DoAsync`) is only appropriate if you need the tasks to be run sequentially - if you want them to be concurrent then you need to set them all off and *then* await them.

Comment: @AntP Thanks! That's exactly what I meant as a `chain of asyncronous calls`. Maybe I should say `sequential asyncronous peaces of work` instead. And  your second case is in my first example - method `DoSomethingTwice`.